# Import javax.ejb.Schedule cannot be resolved

Tags: java, ejb

I have a problem, eclipse say that it cannot found javax.ejb.Schedule (or Schedules) but no problem with other class like javax.ejb.MessageDriven.
I work on a very big application that I don't really know.
So my question is how to resolve this? Or a way to look for?

Comment: What JEE Version are you using?

Comment: What JEE Version JEE 5, JEE 6 or 7? On witch application server.

Comment: The application server is a JBoss 4.0 and I don't found for the JEE version, sorry.

Comment: Jboss 4 is a JEE5 Application server, if I am not mistaken Schedule has only become available with JEE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoos 4 is a JEE5 compliant Server, hence JEE6 features are not available.

Comment: Ok so I have to find an other way to do this. Thanks