# messageDriven & Timer on Java EE 5

Tags: java, timer, ejb

I would like to execute the onMessage(Message message) method, from a class which implement MessageListener, only when a timer allow it (for example 'read' message between 14:00 and 15:00).
Actually I have a @MessageDriven class which receive message instantly.

But like it's said on this post I can't use ejb Schedule: 
[Import javax.ejb.Schedule cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24448063/3607733)

In what direction look for?

**edit :** I want message can be send all the day (I know do that) but the class who receive can do it only between 2 and 3

Comment: So... between 2 and 3 you want to send JMS messages to some class? Or within 2 and 3 you want to allow a JMS service to receive messages? Really vague question.

Comment: I want to allow to receive between 2 and 3. Sorry for being vague